# Error with Qhull. How could I correct it?

Tags: qhull

Basically, I am using qhull for some simple c++ implementations

```
dhcp-18-189-48-131:qhull-2012.1_2$ cat sample_input.txt 
3 #
4
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
0 0 0
dhcp-18-189-48-131:qhull-2012.1_2$ qhull sample_input.txt 
QH7036 qhull warning: missing space after flag s(73); reserved for menu. Skipped.
```

However, my programmes hangs with such error.... Could anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by doing

$ qhull < sample_input.txt

instead...